# Use html (image tag) among the texts in android application database

Tags: java, android, android-database

Hi
Can I use html tag among the text in database?
Like this image:
[Click to veiw image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lhfy2.png)

Or if it is impossible:
How I can use images among the text in android (database)?

Comment: you can store text (with html tags) to database. for image, u should convert image into byte array and then store it into database